# Calculation of a certain operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $$T_n (b) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_k$$ where the sequence $(a_k) \subset \Bbb C$ was chosen only in such a way that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k b_k$ converges for all sequences $(b) \in l^p$ for some $1<p<\infty$.

What is $||T_n||$? I have shown it is bounded above by the answer which I suspect is correct, namely $$(\sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_k|^q)^{1/q}$$ where $1/p + 1/q =1$, but I cannot show that this norm is actually attained. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set
$$ b_k = A_n^{-1}\overline{a_k}\lvert a_k \rvert^{q-2}, $$
where
$$ A_n^p = \sum_{k=1}^n \left\lvert \overline{a_k}\lvert a_k \rvert^{q-2} \right\rvert^p = \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k \rvert^{p(q-1)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k \rvert^q.  $$
(This is a fairly standard miraculous trick, that you can cook up from first principles once you know what it's supposed to do...) Then
$$ T_n(b) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k = A_n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k \rvert^q = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k \rvert^q \right)^{1-1/p} = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k \rvert^q \right)^{1/q}, $$
so your bound is attained.

Comment: I was close! I just didn't have the $A_n$. That said, where does your second equality come from? (the one between the first two sums). EDIT: Nevermind, I used another miraculous trick to figure it out, haha.

Comment: Why is the sequence $(b_k)$ in $l^p$?

Comment: In fact, proving that this sequence was p-summable would end the problem on the spot.

Comment: Because $a_k$ must live in $l_q$, and the norm of this $b_k$ is equal to $\lVert a_k \rVert_q^{q/p} = \lVert a_k \rVert_q^{q-1} $. Or, technically I'm not using a sequence of length $n$, so I can just set the terms beyond $b_n$ equal to zero, and then I have no trouble.